# Compile Typescript to web development

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web

Im having problems to compile [this project](https://github.com/JulioDoAr/snake-game/tree/develop) and execute it correctly on the browser. Actualy the "master" branch works correctly, but im working with the branch "develop".

Is a simple web project with 1 html loading 1 ts/js that has imports to others ts/js files. I was triying to do it with Typescript to learn but im having troubles with the imports in js.

The problem has appeared after divide the project in multiples files and **I think that is about the compilation mode related with the modules**

The error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at Application.js:2
```

I have been triying with other targets and modules, but the error is always similar. Am I missing something? Am I wrong with my knowledge about create a simple web page?

If you need more information or is duplicated, dont care about ask or write, I couldnt find any related that helps me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

What browsers are you targeting?

If you want to target browsers with no native module support, you would need to use a module bundler like webpack/rollup, or a module loader like AMDJS or RequireJS.

If you want to target modern browsers with native module support, use "module": "es2015" in tsconfig.json and include your entrypoint with `<script type="module" ...>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules for more info on modules.

See https://caniuse.com/#search=modules for browser support.

Comment: Thanks you, it was the problem!